# How to check if a literal object is accord with a type or interface in runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, type-conversion, tsc

like this:

```
interface IPeople {
    name: string;
    age?: number;
    family?: null | boolean
}


const p = {
    age: 10,
    family: false
}
```

i want to write an function to judge this logic:

1. name is required,if not return false
2. every member must equalTo it is type,eg:`{age:'ddd'}` is return false

i know typescript will check interface type in complier,But i wanna check in runtime. because, the data may come from promise await

How could i do this?

Comment: typeguard is your friend here

Comment: indeed, there is no typescript in runtime, you'll have to write a custom checker and call it when you need it

Comment: You can also use io-ts